# cannot migrate from Django sqlite3 to postgres, getting "psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation doest not exist" error

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to migrate the sqlite3 db from my Django app to postgres db. I have tried all the tutorials out there but cant seem to solve this error when I try to run 'python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb' or 'python manage.py migrate'. I have installed psycopg2 as well.

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

The error is
"psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "users_postcategory" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ategory"."name", "users_postcategory"."name" FROM "users_pos..."

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVL3T.png)

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt8Xc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding `public.`

```
con = psycopg2.connect(
            host = 'localhost',
            user = 'postgres',
            password = '2356216',
            database = 'excursion'
        )
        cursor = con.cursor()
        sql = ''
        if lang == 'ru':
            sql = f"""SELECT ID, Name_ru, Description_ru, Photo, Point_width, Point_longitude, Link
            FROM memorable
            JOIN communication ON public.communication.memorableid = public.memorable.id 
            WHERE communication.RouteID = {ExcID}"""
        if lang == 'en':
            sql = f"""SELECT ID, Name, Description, Photo, Point_width, Point_longitude, Link 
            FROM memorable 
            JOIN communication ON communication.memorableid = memorable.id 
            WHERE communication.RouteID = {ExcID}"""
        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        return result
```